# How long does it take for fossil fuels to renew?

Tags: fossil-fuel, time

Overtime, we've located, drilled, and used a large portion of our planet's **fossil fuels.** Fossil fuels are found underground, and are dug up to be used as a form of energy, *(ex: Oil found by drilling into the ground and extracting it from the surface through a long pipe)* but it's also becoming an issue as to **we might be running out of easily possessable fossil fuel.**

If I had control over the process of fossil fuel consumption in the entire world, I'd **terminate all fossil fuel extraction until further notice,** because if people are going to avoid running out of fossil fuels, we are go

So my question is:

> Approximately ***how long*** of a wait is it until the majority of extracted fossil fuels are **renewed?**

Comment: Near-duplicate: [How much oil is created each year?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/571/94)

Comment: should I delete it?

Comment: No, just mark it as a duplicate.